# How to add another website by using iframe in a webpage by using html

Tags: html, iframe, styles, head

which tag we will use for adding another webpage  and how to remake it's size full length I have tried by using CSS in html of head section

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Iframes</h2>
<p>You can use the height and width attributes to specify the size of the iframe:</p>

<iframe src="demo.html" width="100%" title="Iframe Example" style="height: 100vh"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

try this code and you get the full width and height for an iframe tag.